# Using If in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-serialization, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

HI i am trying to use if in an xsl to transform an input xml to other xml. 
Could able to achieve to some part unable to get accurate output. Help would be glad.

Input Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Music>
<Music_Model>
    <Electronic>Guitar</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <No_of_used>
        <info>4</info>
    </No_of_used>
    <Music_info>
        <Value>1234566</Value>
        <Description>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </Description>
    </Music_info>
</Music_Model>
<Music_Model>
    <Electronic>Piano</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <No_of_used>
        <info>2</info>
    </No_of_used>
</Music_Model>
<Music_Model>
    <Electronic>Guitar123</Electronic>
    <Beats>Flute</Beats>
    <No_of_used>
        <info>3</info>
    </No_of_used>
    <Music_info>
        <Value>128888902</Value>
        <Description>
            <Value>2</Value>
        </Description>
    </Music_info>
</Music_Model>
<Music_Model>
    <Electronic>tabala</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <No_of_used>
        <info>40</info>
    </No_of_used>
    <Music_info>
        <Value>1298932</Value>
    </Music_info>
</Music_Model>
</Music>
```

Note: In the above input xml. I was interested in "If input xml have NO **Musci_info** element and also having **Music_info** but NO **Description** then the output xml should use elements **No_of_used** and should display only its value. If **Music_info** element and its values are available the output should be normal. I could achieve the elimination but unable to get the acurate.

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Music>
<Record>
    <Electronic>Guitar</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <music_info_value>1234566</music_info_value>
    <test_level>1</test_level>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Electronic>Guitar123</Electronic>
    <Beats>Flute</Beats>
    <music_info_value>128888902</music_info_value>
    <test_level>2</test_level>
</Record>
<not_found>
    <product>2</product>
</not_found>
</Music>
```

Output Displaying with the code i worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Music>
<Record>
    <Electronic>Guitar</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <music_info_value>1234566</music_info_value>
    <test_level>1</test_level>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Electronic>Guitar123</Electronic>
    <Beats>Flute</Beats>
    <music_info_value>128888902</music_info_value>
    <test_level>2</test_level>
</Record>
<Record>
    <Electronic>tabala</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <music_info_value>1298932</music_info_value>
    <test_level/>
</Record>
<not_found>
    <product>4</product>
</not_found>
<not_found>
    <product>3</product>
</not_found>
<not_found>
    <product>40</product>
</not_found>
 </Music>
```

Code I worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Music>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Music_Model">
            <xsl:if test="//Music_Model/Music_info!=Music_info ">
                <Record>
                    <Electronic>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Electronic"/>
                    </Electronic>
                    <Beats>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Beats"/>
                    </Beats>
                    <music_info_value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Music_info/Value"/>
                    </music_info_value>
                    <test_level>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Music_info/Description/Value"/>
                    </test_level>
                </Record>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Music_Model">
            <xsl:if test="//Music_Model/Music_info!=Music_info">
                <not_found>
                    <product>
                        <xsl:value-of select="No_of_used/info"/>
                    </product>
                </not_found>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Music>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler push style style-sheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <Music>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Music_Model[    Music_info/Description ]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Music_Model[not(Music_info/Description)]"/>
 </Music>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Music_Model">  
 <Record> 
  <xsl:copy-of select="Electronic|Beats"/> 
  <music_info_value><xsl:value-of select="Music_info/Value" /></music_info_value>
  <test_level><xsl:value-of select="Music_info/Description/Value" /></test_level>
 </Record>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Music_Model[not(Music_info/Description)]">  
 <not_found>
   <product><xsl:value-of select="No_of_used/info" /></product>
 </not_found>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces output as per your stated requirements, with the <not_found> nodes last.

```
<Music>
  <Record>
    <Electronic>Guitar</Electronic>
    <Beats>Pad</Beats>
    <music_info_value>1234566</music_info_value>
    <test_level>1</test_level>
  </Record>
  <Record>
    <Electronic>Guitar123</Electronic>
    <Beats>Flute</Beats>
    <music_info_value>128888902</music_info_value>
    <test_level>2</test_level>
  </Record>
  <not_found>
    <product>2</product>
  </not_found>
  <not_found>
    <product>40</product>
  </not_found>
</Music>
```

### Note

Note that the tabala (product 40), is included in the not_found list, because as your rules stated, it does not have a Description.

Comment: Thanks Durkin. I have understand clearly with your example how a  template works. I shall learn to embedded the code in a single logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you just did it in one loop checking for the presence of Music_Info/Description, it would let you know if you should output not found or not, so this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Music>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Music_Model">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Music_info/Description">
                    <Record>
                        <Electronic>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Electronic"/>
                        </Electronic>
                        <Beats>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Beats"/>
                        </Beats>
                        <music_info_value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Music_info/Value"/>
                        </music_info_value>
                        <test_level>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Music_info/Description/Value"/>
                        </test_level>
                    </Record>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <not_found>
                        <product>
                            <xsl:value-of select="No_of_used/info"/>
                        </product>
                    </not_found>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Music>
</xsl:template>
```

when applied to your data, produces the following output:

```
<Music>
    <Record>
        <Electronic>Guitar</Electronic>
        <Beats>Pad</Beats>
        <music_info_value>1234566</music_info_value>
        <test_level>1</test_level>
    </Record>
    <not_found>
        <product>2</product>
    </not_found>
    <Record>
        <Electronic>Guitar123</Electronic>
        <Beats>Flute</Beats>
        <music_info_value>128888902</music_info_value>
        <test_level>2</test_level>
    </Record>
    <not_found>
        <product>40</product>
    </not_found>
</Music>
```

which seems like what you want

Comment: By my understanding of the OP's requirements, this is wrong. The not_found nodes should be last, not interspersed, as per provided expected output.

Comment: Thanks Woody, The answer isnt accurate format but produced the output intended.

Comment: @ WOODY: In real time, i guess your logic would be working fine when we consider the cost basis and time to process using Java Beans.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't realised that the order was significant, so I just did it in the order it came.